# Python -- Why does mtime precede the command that modifies the file?

Tags: python, numpy

```
from time import time
from os.path import getmtime
import numpy as np

path = '/tmp/test.npz'
print(time()); np.savez(path, **{'a': 1, 'b': 2}); print(getmtime(path))
```

gives me

```
1562961763.9898937
1562961763.9877298
```

Why is mtime smaller? This would mean the last modified time of `path` was *before* the time when the modifying command ran. How is this possible?!

Comment: Unable to replicate this effect (Mac OsX), weird. What os are you using?

Comment: Filesystems generally don't store timestamps with the full resolution of your system clock.  I would guess that the mtime got rounded down to a multiple of the timestamp granularity, introducing an error that was larger than the actual amount of time the `.savez()` took.

Comment: @Jmonsky I'm on Debian.

Comment: @jasonharper Sounds plausible. But if this is really the case, how do I solve this?

Comment: Is there really anything that needs to be solved here?  If this is somehow creating an actual problem for you, putting `time.sleep(0.05)` before the `.savez()` would probably be sufficient to guarantee that the mtime is later than the starting time.  (On a recent OS at least - the original FAT disk format had a 2-second time granularity!)

Comment: @jasonharper Sounds like a solution! Surprised that the original FAT has a 2s granularity -- that sounds crazily bad!

Comment: @finefoot From around 20 manual trials of mine, yes.